# Filter codebuild push event

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-codebuild

In my project, I have buildspec.yml that deploys my app and creates a new release on GitHub.
If I create a new CodeBuild project with the yml file above and watch master branch with GitHub push webhook, it keeps releasing new versions forever...

It seems that if I watch "push" event, the webhook also triggers a new build if new releases (or new tag creation?) is detected.
And that release triggers another webhook "push" event, entering infinite release loop.

Is there any way to make the build only reactive to real pushes?

(or perhaps, is making new releases in buildspec.yml not a good practice...?)

Answer (score 1):

The [push event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) does indeed detect tag and branch creation.

But its event payload also include "size": The number of commits in the push.

If that size is 0, your listener won't have to trigger any build.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, although the document says "size" is the number of commits IN THE PUSH, seems it counts all commits from the repository creation... :(
I ended up made api gateway+lambda to filter my webhooks.

Comment: @sora OK, strange: maybe GitHub support would have more on this.

Answer (score 1):

There is native support for filtering your webhook events in CodeBuild. Details in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-github-pull-request.html#sample-github-pull-request-filter-webhook-events-console. You can set a filter to opt-out of builds, when it is triggered due to a release tag.